# How to concatenate elements of two list to form a new list (pandas.DataFrame)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to use **DataFrame** from **Pandas**. How can I append calculated values in a for loop to pandas.DataFrame Sequentially ?.

One way around is to push all calculated values into an arrays (**wlines** and **peaktype**) and select elements based on indexing into a new array (**new_list**) and pass the **new_list** to DataFrame. For example (see below):

```
wlines = [427.397, 431.958, 450.235, 557.029,  587.092, 605.613, 645.629, 
          665.223, 669.923, 681.311, 690.468]

peaktype = [0.5,    0.5,    1.0,    0.5,    1.0,    0.5,    0.5,    0.5,     
            0.5,    0.5,    0.5]

new_list = [427.397, 0.5]
```

Comment: That's a pretty reasonable way.

Comment: @AmiTavory Substitute your comment as answer please. Thank you.